# How to convert time format?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format

My Windows date format is Month/Date/Year. If I want set StartTime with format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", How can I do that. I try the following code.

```
DateTime StartTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2011/01/04 09:30:00", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", null);
```

But StartTime come out with 1/4/2011  9:30:00 AM.
                          (month/date/year hh:mm:ss)

Comment: `StartTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is using your format to parse the date correctly, but it is displaying it by default.  To display it in the format you created it in you will either need to use [String.Format](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/) or you can even use 'ToString()' with a [pattern](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm).

Answer (score 11):

You're parsing the time correctly, but displaying it with the default format.  Try `StartTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: +1: Calling `Parse` takes a string and turns it into a DateTime object. Calling `ToString()` takes a DateTime and turns it into a string.

Answer (score 4):

This code works correctly, and you have a strong-typed DateTime object now.

If you wish to then output it in the format you have above, then you call ToString() with the format in your second argument.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN is your friend:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

You can also set a breakpoint to inspect the value of StartTime, to figure out what is really in it.